# set wget to download 10 file at same time

Tags: download, wget, sametime

i have this code - links.txt include like 10k link . but wget download first link and after finished download the next link , is there any way to tell wget to start download 10 links or more at same time so the whole time need to download will be shorter.
thanks

```
!wget --load-cookies cookies.txt -i links.txt
```

I appreciate your help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: @Daweo i use google colab